# Does std::ranges::views::enumerate use the wrong type for indexing on GCC?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std-ranges, size-t, c++23

First, using Range-v3, I noticed that

```cpp
std::vector<int> v;
auto w = v | ranges::views::enumerate;
auto [x, y] = *w.begin();
static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::size_t, decltype(x)>);
```

which makes sense to me because [`std::size_t` is the right type to use for indexing into objects, as far as I've understood](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t).

Then, with C++20 ranges, the static assertion fails. Instead, the following passes,

```cpp
static_assert(std::is_same_v<long, decltype(x)>);
```

but `long` is not the same as `std::size_t` on my system, where I verified that

```cpp
static_assert(std::is_same_v<unsigned long, std::size_t>)
```

---

On, GCC 13.2.1, here's [the example](https://godbolt.org/z/KceMq4dxE).

Comment: That's going to depend on the type of `v`.

Comment: @user17732522, why does it matter?

Comment: Suppose `v` is a container and has `size_type = unsigned short` and `difference_type = short` for memory efficiency reasons because the container type may never hold more elements than fit these types. Then `enumerate` should not produce a much larger type. And the other way around a range's size could be larger than `std::size_t` can hold. A range doesn't need to hold each element in memory at the same time.

Comment: Also, `ranges::views::enumerate` uses `difference_type` for the first element of the tuple, i.e. it produces a signed result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does `std::ranges::views::enumerate` use the wrong type for indexing on GCC?

No.

`std::views::enumerate` is [specified](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.enumerate.iterator) to use `range_difference_t<Base>` as its index value. gcc implementation is correct to the specification.

On the other hand, range-v3's [implementation](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/view/enumerate.hpp#L109C35-L109C46) [used](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/9aa41d6b8ded2cf5e8007e66a0efd1ab33dbf9a5/include/range/v3/iterator/traits.hpp#L98-L102) `make_unsigned<range_difference_t<Base>>` as its index value.

Signed seems like a much better choice here, given that you probably want subtraction to be sensible. Although there's no discussion of this choice as far as I can see in [P2164](https://wg21.link/p2164) (or any revision thereof).

---

> but `long` is not the same as `std::size_t` on my system

`long` is not the same as `std::size_t` on any system. `long` is signed and `size_t` is unsigned.